# PHP long poll fails

Tags: php, long-polling

I have this loop to long poll:

```
$time = time(); //send a blank response after 15sec
    while((time() - $time) < 15) {
            $last_modif = filemtime("./logs.txt");
            if($_SESSION['lasttime'] != $last_modif) {
                $_SESSION['lasttime'] = $last_modif;
                $logs = file_get_contents("./logs.txt");
                print nl2br($logs);
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                die();
        }

        usleep(10000);
    }
```

problem is: the "if" condition is never entered in the middle of the while loop, even if logs.txt is modified. I have to wait 15sec till the next call to this file to obtain the updated content (so it becomes a regular, "setTimeout style" AJAX polling, not a long-poll). Any idea why ?

Comment: we can't see where $_SESSION['lasttime'] and $last_modif changes, you try it without the if and check if it works

Comment: sorry I didn't add them because I know they are not relevant :/ my question was answered though, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the filemtime() function : its results are cached. Thus each time your loop is executed the timestamp's the same for 15 seconds.

I have not tried it myself, but [according to w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_filemtime.asp) :

> The result of this function are cached. Use clearstatcache() to clear the cache.

Hope that helps !

Comment: you should not link to w3schools, thanks for the answer though, works like a charm!

Comment: W3Schools? That seems an odd place to go for PHP advice. [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) says the same thing though, so w3schools can't be all bad.

Comment: Yeah well it's not all that bad, and I already had the website opened for another thing I needed to check on sql. I kinda like how it's concise.